# wxpython, find control based on its name

Tags: python, wxpython

I was wondering if it is possible (I'm sure it is) to get a reference to a control based on the name of the control.

Something like `control = findcontrol("btnProduct"+buttonNumber)`

You probably catch my drift... (and yes, I am a newby in wxPython)

Regards,

Dennis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I ended up with this:

```
        control = getattr(self, "btnProduct%s" % (str(buttonNo)))
        control.SetLabel("")
```

Thanks Mark for steering me in the right direction!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the frame instance's FindWindowByName() method, assuming you passed a unique name parameter to the widget or you might be able to use the frame instance's FindWindowByLabel() method. You can also find by id, but I don't really recommend that since it's better not to manage the ids yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on the python [locals() and globals()](http://diveintopython.net/html_processing/locals_and_globals.html) functions.

For instance you could:

```
control = locals()['btnProduct' + buttonNumber]
```

Of course their is probably a much better way to do what you want.  Put your controls into a dictionary maybe?